# Ergodicity of a sequence of independent blocks

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, stationary-processes

I am stuck with the problem given below, more precisely, with the part regarding ergodicity. I have a proof, also given in what follow, but it does not seem to be correct; well, at least, it does not sound like a solid mathematical proof.

**Problem (Independent blocks, Exercise 7.1.6 in Durrett):**

Let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ be a stationary sequence. Let $n < \infty$ and let $Y_1, Y_2, \dotsc$ be a sequence so that $(Y_{nk+1}, \dotsc, Y_{n(k+1)})$, $k \geq 0$ are i.i.d. and $(Y_1, Y_2, \dotsc, Y_n) = (X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n)$. Finally
let $\nu$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}$, independent of Y, and let $Z_m = Y_{\nu + m}$ for $m \geq 1$. Show that Z is stationary and ergodic.

**Proof (ergodicity only):**

We know that, for an i.i.d. sequence, Kolmogorov's 0-1 law implies that the tail $\sigma$-field is trivial (Example 7.1.6 in Durrett). Therefore, the tail $\sigma$-field of the process formed by the (independent) blocks of the $Y$ sequence is trivial.
This tail $\sigma$-field is
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{T}_Y & = \cap_{k = 1}^\infty \sigma(Y_{nk + 1}, \dots, Y_{n(k + 1)}, Y_{n(k + 1) + 1}, \dots, Y_{n(k + 2)}, \dots) \\
  & = \sigma(Y_{n + 1}, \dots) \cap \sigma(Y_{2n + 1}, \dots) \cap \sigma(Y_{3n + 1}, \dots) \cap \dots \\
  & = \mathcal{F}_{n + 1} \cap \mathcal{F}_{2n + 1} \cap \mathcal{F}_{3n + 1} \cap \dots
\end{align*}
Now, let us have a look at the tail $\sigma$-field of the $Z$ sequence:
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal{T}_Z & = \cap_{k = 1}^\infty \sigma(Z_k, Z_{k + 1}, \dots) = \cap_{k = 1}^\infty \sigma(Y_{\nu + k}, Y_{\nu + k + 1}, \dots) \\
  & = \sigma(Y_{\nu + 1}, \dots) \cap \sigma(Y_{\nu + 2}, \dots) \cap \sigma(Y_{\nu + 3}, \dots) \cap \dots \\
  & = \mathcal{F}_{\nu + 1} \cap \mathcal{F}_{\nu + 2} \cap \mathcal{F}_{\nu + 3} \cap \dots
\end{align*}
It can be seen that the $Z$ sequence of $\sigma$-algebras is seamless: depending on the outcome of $\nu$, it starts from $\mathcal{F}_{\nu + 1}$ (from $\mathcal{F}_{n + 1}$ in the worst case) and has not further gaps. On the other hand, the $Y$ sequence of $\sigma$-algebras starts from exactly $\mathcal{F}_{n + 1}$ and does have gaps. The more terms involved in an intersection, the smaller the resulting set. Hence, $\mathcal{T}_Z \subset \mathcal{T}_Y$, and, therefore, the $Z$ sequence is ergodic.

The idea here is to prove the ergodicity property of the $Z$ sequence by showing that the tail $\sigma$-field of this sequence is trivial, and this is done by showing that this tail $\sigma$-field is contained in the tail $\sigma$-field of the sequence formed by the independent blocks of the $Y$ sequence.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by $\mathcal F_{\nu+1}$? (because the index is random) And is $\nu$ independent of the considered $(X_k)$ and $(Y_k)$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, $\mathcal{F}_k$ is just the notation that I use to denote $\sigma(Y_k, Y_{k+1}, \dotsc)$. I was trying to show how the elements of $\mathcal{T}_Y$ and $\mathcal{T}_Z$ correspond to each other. Regarding $\nu$, as nothing else is mentioned in the exercise, it is safe to assume that $\nu$ is independent from the rest.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, I was just going through the description of the exercise again and realized that I had missed out "independent of Y" with respect to $\nu$. I have updated by my question. Sorry for this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(Y_k)$ is $n$-dependent because the blocks of $n$ are independent. Using the fact that $\nu$ is independent of $Y$, we get that $Z$ is $2n$-independent. Then we use a similar argument as in the zero-one law.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you please explain in more detail your first statement? I got the decomposition of the event $\{ Z_m \leq t \}$, but I do not know how one should reason in order to relate this decomposition with the corresponding $\sigma$-algebras. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't understand because there was a silly mistake, which is now corrected (it's the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $Y_{m+i}$ and $\eta$, there is no intersection).

Comment: If I interpret it correctly, $\vee$ denotes the union. Then, the last formula means that the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $Z$ is included in a set which is larger than the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $Y$ due to the union with $\sigma(\eta)$. So, I do not see how the conclusion follows, i.e., how one tail is contained in the other one.

Comment: @Ivan I've added details. It actually uses independence.

Comment: Sorry for keeping asking you, but I really want to understand. Should not $\sigma(\nu) \cup \mathcal{F}$ be composed of sets of the form $\{ \nu \in I \} \cup F$? So, they are unions, not intersections. Therefore, the result should be larger than the tail $\sigma$-field of the block sequence. Thank you!

Comment: My previous attempt was not really good. I think there is something simpler.

Comment: Please have a look at the proof given as a separate answer.

Comment: I have changed the proof that I posted earlier. I was carefully looking at what I had written and could not find a reason for the $Z$ sequence to be $2n$-independent. When you partition this sequence into blocks of $2n$ elements, two subsequent blocks are not independent since they share the same block of the $Y$ sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I would be grateful if somebody could confirm that the following proof is correct.

**Proof (ergodicity only):**

By definition, the $Z$ sequence is ergodic if
$$
  P((Z_1, Z_2, \dotsc) \in B) \in \{0, 1\}
$$
whenever $B \in \mathcal{R}^{\{0, 1, \dotsc\}}$ has
$$
  \{ (Z_1, Z_2, \dotsc) \in B \} = \{ (Z_2, Z_3, \dotsc) \in B \}. \tag{$\ast$}
$$
Let $A = \{ (Z_1, Z_2, \dotsc) \in B \}$, which is shift invariant according to ($\ast$).
We are to show now that $P(A) \in \{0, 1\}$.
By iteratively applying the shift operator to ($\ast$), $A \in \sigma(Z_k, Z_{k + 1}, \dotsc)$ for $k \geq 1$; hence,
$$
  A \in \cap_{k = 1}^\infty \sigma(Z_k, Z_{k + 1}, \dotsc) = \mathcal{T}_Z, \text{ the tail $\sigma$-field of the sequence.}
$$
Next, for any $B \in \mathcal{R}$, due to the independence of $Y$ and $\nu$,
$$
  \{ Z_m \in B \} = \{ Y_{m + \nu} \in B \} = \cup_{k = 1}^n \{ \nu = k \} \cap \{ Y_{m + k} \in B \} \subseteq \cup_{k = 1}^n \{ Y_{m + k} \in B \}.
$$
Thus,
$$
  \sigma(Z_m) \subseteq \sigma(Y_{m + 1}, \dotsc, Y_{m + n}).
$$
Consequently,
$$
  \mathcal{T}_Z \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y = \cap_{k = 1}^\infty \sigma(Y_k, Y_{k + 1}, \dotsc), \text{ the tail $\sigma$-field of the block sequence.}
$$
Finally, by Kolmogorov's zero-one law, the tail $\sigma$-field of the block sequence, $\mathcal{T}_Y$, is trivial.
Hence, $P(A) \in \{0, 1\}$ as $A \in \mathcal{T}_Z \subseteq \mathcal{T}_Y$.